# Clean way to handle different exceptions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, exceptions, clean-code, error-handling

I'm Java developer and I'm now learning Javascript creating a personal project.
I don't know how to handle different errors in Javascript in a clean way and I can't find a good solution on the web.

I'm consuming some external APIs using axios. The external resource use a pagination system, so when I get back a 204 status code means that there are not more pages to consume, so I've to perform a different action than the others error.

In Java I would have created a MyException class and added another catch. How to do in Javascript?

I don't really like how I do it. There's a better or cleaner way to do it? Maybe I should save 'NO_PAGE' as global constant?
Here is a code example:

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  try {
    //... Some code using axios
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.request._currentRequest.res.statusCode === 204) {
      throw Error('NO_PAGE');
    } else {
      throw Error("Can't get goods: \n" + error.message);
    }
  }
};
```

```
const myOtherFunc = async () => {
  try {
    myFunc();
    //... Some code
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.message === 'NO_PAGE') {
      // ...Perform some action;
    }
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer to create custom errors, why don't you do so? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types.

Unfortunately you can't catch specific errors in javascript like you're used to in java. So you still have to match something in an if statement.

```js
catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof CustomError)
```

At least this solution is nicer and less error prone than string matching on error message. Yet, I guess that's also pretty subjective.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the best and the cleanest solution. Thank you @Kleistra